# Is the graph of $y=\frac{k}{x}$ a hyperbola?

Tags: conic-sections

Is the graph of the following inverse relation a hyperbola?$$y=\frac kx$$

If yes, is it the only kind of hyperbola whose equation is an explicit function?

Comment: You mean: an expmicit function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $$y=\frac kx$$
is a hyperbola. In fact, it is a type of *rectangular hyperbola* which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Hyperbola_with_equation_y=A/x).

This means that a function $y(x)$ that takes the form
$$y-k=\frac {k}{x-h}$$
is also hyperbola.

<s>I suppose that is the only type of hyperbolas that is a function since any rotation of this type of hyperbolas will immediately cause the plot to fail the vertical line test.</s>

Thanks to @Blue:

> Any (non-degenerate) hyperbola with a vertical asymptote is the graph of a function. Rectangularity is not a requirement.

Comment: Any (non-degenerate) hyperbola with a vertical asymptote is the graph of a function. Rectangularity is not a requirement.

Comment: @Blue oh yes you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* a hyperbola, and you can even derive it from the original formula of a hyperbola using analytic geometry.

Let $a$ and $b$ be the axes of the $y=1/x$ hyperbola, while $x$ and $y$ are the axes of the $y^2-x^2=k$ hyperbola. If $a=(x+y)/2$ and $b=(y-x)/2$, then graphing the original $y^2-x^2=k$ formula by replacing y with b and x with a respectively we get the exact same hyperbola as $y=k/x$.